# RollingFileAppender (Log4net) is not accepting the filenamePattern

Tags: xml, log4net

I expect to have 10 files called 
Console.1.log, 
Console.2.log,
Console.3.log... etc.

What i got is: Console.log.1, Console.log.2... same as when i don't put any settings...

I've tried to change the namespace of

```
`<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="${APPDATA}\\product\\Console.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <MaxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <MaximumFileSize value="1KB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" >
      <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger %message%newline" />
  </layout>
  <threshold value="DEBUG" />

<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
    <param name="activeFileName" value="${APPDATA}\\product\\Console.log"/>
    <param name="fileNamePattern" value="${APPDATA}\\product\\Console.${%i}.log"/>
    <param name="maxIndex" value="0"/>
    <param name="minIndex" value="10"/>
</rollingPolicy>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With version 1.2.11 the following does what you want:

```
<preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>
```

It seems that there might be an issue if you role by date, though (see last comment):
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-64